# No view found for id 0x7f0800c2 (.... id/profile_frame) for fragment ProfileFragment{763e0e0 #2 id=0x7f0800c2}

Tags: android, button, layout, fragment

I've already taken a look at some of the other questions regarding this error but I've either not fully understood them, or they don't work for my solution, so I would like to ask it here.

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title when trying to press a button to go from one fragment to another one.

**Button code:**

```
    mTextViewShowUploads.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openImagesActivity();
        }
    });
```

**Go from one fragment to another code:**

```
private void openImagesActivity() {
    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.profile_frame, profileFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**Layout of second fragment**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProfileFragment"
    android:id="@+id/profile_frame"
    >
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/changeProfilePicBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Change profile picture"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26999998" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePicView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/changeProfilePicBtn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="467dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

**Activity layout code**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    >


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_colors"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items"> 
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/main_nav"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mMainFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
    mMainNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_nav);

    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    weatherFragment = new WeatherFragment();
    uploadFragment = new UploadFragment();
    searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
    profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

    setFragment(homeFragment);

    mMainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_home :

                    setFragment(homeFragment);

                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_weather :

                    setFragment(weatherFragment);

                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_upload :

                    setFragment(uploadFragment);

                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_search :

                    setFragment(searchFragment);

                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_profile :

                    setFragment(profileFragment);

                    return true;

                default:

                    return false;



            }

        }
    });

}

private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(!(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null)) {
        Intent i = new Intent (HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: upload your fragment_upload layout code

Comment: Edited the post to show fragment_upload code.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Can you clarify on this please?

Comment: `Fragment` should be inside `Activity`. I want to check that `Activity` and layout of that activity where you want to attach the fragment

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman okay, I've updated the post to show the activity layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to pass `R.id.profile_frame` as the container in which to replace the fragment, and `profile_frame` is the id of the container layout in your fragment's layout. You want to pass the container layout id of the activity in this line:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.profile_frame, profileFragment);
```

Change that line to:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, profileFragment);
```

As I can see `main_frame` is the id of the container you wanna show your fragment in.

Comment: This works for me, thank you. Side question however, Once I've pressed the button, the navigation bar button remains highlighted on the first fragment and doesn't change to the highlighted button of the next fragment. Any way I can fix this? Again, thank you